# AWS: Cloudformation template: Install Windows Feature questions

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Below is snippet of AWS Cloudformation template that I want to use PowerShell installing Web Server Windows Feature after create Windows Server 2012 R2 (64 bits). However, AWS Cloudformation succesfully create Windows Server 2012 EC2 instance but not install Web Server role.

```
        "commands" : {
          "1-install-roles" : {
            "command" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [
             "if not \"None\" EQU \"", 
              { "Ref" : "Roles" },
              "\" (powershell -Command \"Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature ",
              { "Ref" : "Roles" },
              " -Restart\")"]]
            }
          },
```

Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you obtained this from a cloudformation template example. I would suggest trying if it works with the AMI(s) that are in the template. If not you can use AMI's that already have IIS installed on them. That's what I am doing as a work around as I ran into the same issue.

UPDATE: I researched and tested more. The powershell command actually should be:

```
Add-WindowsFeature
```

not

```
Install-WindowsFeature
```

Here are the commands I ran in PowerShell to get the Add-WindowsFeature working as expected:

```
set-executionpolicy bypass
ImportSystemModules
Import-Module servermanager
```